# adding jpegs to vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

i am using itextsharp and creating a PDF with images.

currently the images i am using in the application are on my desktop, but i will need to make an installation file that will put the images in a specified directory on the users computer and be able to call them from the specific directory.

1. how do i include pictures with my build?
2. how do i reference the pictures? currently i am using:

   Dim jpeg3 As Image = Image.GetInstance(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\2.jpg")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How and where do you add the pictures?
If you simply added them to the project as if they were code files (using "add existing item"), then check the Properties for the file in the solution explorer (Build Action, and Copy To Output Directory are useful), and also the Application Files button/window (under the project settings -> Publish). This is useful for distributing the files along with the application (for both debug and release), deployed in a specific sub-directory.

If you added the files to the project's resource file, you can use them using the My.Resources namespace.